# How can I get a users profile picture via the facebook sdk (latest way?)

Tags: php, facebook

Looks like a lot of the tutorials online are outdated including anything in stack-overflow and they don't work. Plus facebooks SDK documentation doesn't say anything about it. How would I get a users profile picture ?

What I've seen so far and it doesn't work.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/Facebook_user_id/picture
```

**Figured it out, to get it via the api you do this:**

```
$config = array(
    'redirect' => false,
    'height' => 186,
    'width' => 186,
    'type' => 'normal',
    'is_silhouette' => 0
);
$fb_image = $this->facebook->api('/me/picture', $config);

//print_r($fb_image);
echo "<img src='" . $fb_image['data']['url'] . "'>";
```

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/
click on php-sdk

Comment: works very well, did you replace the facebook_user_id with an actual ID?

Comment: yes, but i updated the post found out how to do it :)

Comment: You can answer your own question its better you move it into answer section.

Comment: Just for information, `/me/picture` == `/{user-in-session}/picture` == `http://graph.facebook.com/{user-in-session}/picture`. So `https://graph.facebook.com/Facebook_user_id/picture` is absolutely fine- I'm not sure what did you find wrong in this!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download a picture to the server, use `CURL` (but be sure that you allow redirection)  or `file_get_contents` with URL you specified. It works well. It should also work with Facebook PHP SDK, too. <sub>[[documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture)]</sub>

If you want to show a picture to the client, just put URL you specified to an image tag

Code:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture/" />
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
http://graph.facebook.com/id/picture?type={small,large,normal,square}
```

example `http://graph.facebook.com/subhanker.chourasia/picture?type=normal`

Comment: tried that, didnt work for me, using my id, it just showed an empty facebook image.

Comment: give me your facebook username or id and I will check for it